# How to get the message content/embed from the message id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to know how to get a message content (specifically the embeds) from the `message id`? Just like you can get the member using a `member id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `on_raw_reaction_add()` example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    embed = msg.embeds[0]
    # do something you want to
```

---

## Command example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def getmsg(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, msgID: int):
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(msgID)
    await ctx.send(msg.embeds[0].description)
```

In the command I'm passing in `channel` and `msgID`, so a sample command execution would like `!getmsg #general 112233445566778899` - the channel must be in the same server that you're executing the command in!

Then I'm getting the message object using the `fetch_message()` coroutine, which allows me to get a list of `embeds` in said message. I then choose the first, and only, embed by choosing position index `0`.

After that, the bot then sends the description (or whatever attribute you'd like) of the embed.

---

**References:**

- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)
- [`Message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)
- [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed) - This is where you can find the different attributes of the embed
- [`commands.command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command) - Command decorator
- [`on_raw_reaction_add()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add)
- [`discord.RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) - The payload returned from the reaction event
- [`RawReactionActionEvent.message_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.message_id) - The ID of the message which was reacted to
- [`RawReactionActionEvent.channel_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.channel_id) - The text channel that the reaction was added in

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the message without having the channel? I ONLY have the message id

Comment: Usually when you get the message ID, there's a way to also get the channel. What's the context of the question? Are you trying to get this in a specific event?

Comment: So I am using `on_raw_reaction_add()` event. I know I can use `on_reaction_add()`, but I don't like the fact that it doesn't tell you if a person reacted to the message if its not in the bot's cache. So in `on_raw_reaction_add()`, you only have the message id. I want to extract the embed from there.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with using `on_raw_reaction_add()`. Bear with me :)

Comment: @Jackie Alright I've updated the answer, I hope it helps!