# discord.py Check content of embed title

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**What I'm trying to do**: I am making a riddle command with my `discord.py` bot. Every time someone runs the command for a new riddle, it removes the most recent message pinned (the author of said message being the bot) and pins the new message. I am trying to make the bot look for a certain keyword in an embed's title, rather than relying on whether the pinned message was sent by the bot or not.

**Problem**: I have not found a way to check the content of an embed title. The only question I found that was mostly related to my question was for [an `on_message()` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64759272/discord-py-detect-message-in-embed-title-or-description), but I wasn't very sure how to incorporate it.

**Code**:

```py
@client.command(aliases=["riddle"],pass_context=True)
@commands.guild_only()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def rid(ctx, prize=None, *, rid=None):
    if prize == None and rid == None:
        await ctx.send('Format: `bl!riddle "cool prize" Sometimes it\'s brown and sticky, what is it?`')
    elif prize is not None and rid == None:
        await ctx.send('Format: `bl!riddle "a nice prize" Fluffy like candy but not a cloud, what am I?`')
    elif prize is not None and rid is not None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title, "Today's Riddle: ", description=rid, color=0x8d78d9) # The embed title the bot would read
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Prize: {prize} | Host: {ctx.message.author}")
        try:
            await ctx.message.delete()
        except:
            pass
        pinner = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        channel = ctx.channel
        pins = await channel.pins()
        x = 1
        while x is not 0:
            for message in pins:
                if message.author.id == 733237477170741280: # this is what I want to replace              
                    await message.unpin()
                    x = x - 1
                else:
                    continue
                if x == 0:
                    break
        await pinner.pin()
```

**Images**:

[image: How the embed looks]

This is what the embed looks like.

**Other questions I have looked at**:

- [With Discord.py, is there a way to read embedded messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62601894/with-discord-py-is-there-a-way-to-read-embedded-messages)
- [How to get the message content/embed from the message id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883534/how-to-get-the-message-content-embed-from-the-message-id)
- [Discord.py Detect message in Embed Title or Description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64759272/discord-py-detect-message-in-embed-title-or-description)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed) object has attributes [`title`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.title) and [`description`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.description). With these, you can access the content of an embed.

```py
@client.command(aliases=["riddle"],pass_context=True)
@commands.guild_only()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def rid(ctx, prize=None, *, rid=None):
    if prize == None and rid == None:
        await ctx.send('Format: `bl!riddle "cool prize" Sometimes it\'s brown and sticky, what is it?`')
    elif prize is not None and rid == None:
        await ctx.send('Format: `bl!riddle "a nice prize" Fluffy like candy but not a cloud, what am I?`')
    elif prize is not None and rid is not None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Today's Riddle: ", description=rid, color=0x8d78d9)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Prize: {prize} | Host: {ctx.message.author}")
        embed_title = embed.title
        embed_desc = embed.description
        ...
```

**EDIT**

In order to get the embed object from a message, you can use `message.embeds`. This will return you a list of embeds that the message has.

Comment: This would be for finding the title and description of the embed sent, yes. However, how would you find the `embed.title` or `embed.description` in a message? Would you have to read the `message.content` and work from there?

Comment: @Bagle you'd use the `message.embeds` attribute, [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20embeds#discord.Message.embeds)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński `message.embeds[0]['title']` does not exist for me